# What's the deal with Java's return type in this example

Tags: java

I keep getting `method must return result of type byte[]`

```
public class MyClass {

  public static byte[] someMethod() {
    try {
        ...
        byte[] someByte = .... ;            
        return someByte;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return someByte;
   }    
}
```

How can I properly return something if there is `try/catch` block?

Comment: You're not taking scope into account. Your last `return` statement doesn't know what `someByte` is.

Comment: That is **not** the error you would get for the code you posted.

Comment: maybe OP has an other variable called `someByte` somewhere in his code but this other variable has a different type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To properly return something it must be declared outside `try{}` scope , and initialized in it (If that requires you to include `try{}` ) . For example :-

```
public class MyClass {

  public static byte[] someMethod() {
    byte[] someByte =null;
       try {
        ...
        someByte = .... ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return someByte;
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This won't compile, since `someByte` is declared within the try block and accessed outside it.

Should be :

```
public class MyClass {
  public static byte[] someMethod() {
    byte[] someByte = null;
    try {
        ...
        someByte = .... ;            
        return someByte;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return someByte;
  }    
}
```

Comment: Although not wrong but I think `return` in `try` is redundant, since we are returning it anyway after `catch`  :)

Answer (score 2):

Your array `someByte` is out of scope

```
public class MyClass {

  public static byte[] someMethod() {
    try {
        ...
        byte[] someByte = .... ;            // scope begins        
        return someByte;                    // scope ends
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return someByte;                        // out of scope
   }    
}
```

instead do this

```
public class MyClass {

  public static byte[] someMethod() {
    byte[] someByte = null ;         // scope begins
    try {          
        someByte = .... ;         
        return someByte;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return someByte;                // scope ends
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `someByte` outside the scope of the try/catch block so that it's visible within the wider scope of the method

```
byte[] someByte = null;
try {
    someByte = .... ;            
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
return someByte;
```

Answer (score 1):

move `byte[] someByte` outside the try block

```
public class MyClass {

      public static byte[] someMethod() {
        byte[] someByte = .... ;
        try {
            ...
            byte[] someByte = .... ;            
            return someByte;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return someByte;
       }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the **SCOPE OF VARIABLE** in picture,basically scope of a variable is the area of code or the number of lines in code where the variable can  accessed with the same value.

so here you  declared somebyte[ ]  inside try block and the scope of variable is only inside the curly braces ,and it is only visible inside that block because you declared it inside the block so when  you are trying to get the value of variable out of block will not get expected results.

```
       try {
    ...
    byte[] someByte = .... ;            
    return someByte;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

so declare it outside the block so the variable is visible to that line of code from where you can access it .

you declare it inside the block so its lifetime  and scope is also inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you **must** declare `someByte` outside of the try/catch block. However, it may be useful to explain why.

The try section of a try/catch block is what is executed during normal operation where there are no exceptions thrown. If an exception is thrown during the execution of a try block, execution will immediately stop. From there, execution will continue in a corresponding catch block (Should an appropriate one be found). To put it simply, it is as if the unused code is simply cut out and the code from the catch block replaces it.

The compiler checks for issues that may arise from, what is essentially, self-modifying code. Although in your example, there may be no chance of `someByte` not being declared, the compiler is unable to say for certain that it will not. it cannot predict whether an exception will be thrown before

```
byte[] someByte = .... ;
```

It is taking the possibility of this occurring:

```
public class MyClass {

  public static byte[] someMethod() {
        ...    // Exception thrown somewhere here
        byte[] someByte = .... ;            
        return someByte;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return someByte;
   }    
}
```

Which means that, essentially, what the JVM acts upon is this:

```
public class MyClass {

  public static byte[] someMethod() {
        ...    // Exception thrown somewhere here
        e.printStackTrace();
        return someByte;
  }    
}
```

If you were to just have typed this into your source file, you would see the obvious issue, you are returning a variable that simply doesn't exist.

By declaring the variable outside of the try block, you are making 100% sure that the variable will be declared with the correct data type and therefore you and the compiler knows that there will be *something* to return, even if it is just the default value for your variable. You can still alter the value of the variable inside your try/catch block if you wish.